# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer in tableau?

Tags: java, list, tableau-api

```
     List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<Object>();
     Resultset rs = selectFromRemoteTable(conn, sourceTableOrQuery);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmds = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount =  rsmds.getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()){
         for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
             colType = rsmds.getColumnTypeName(i);
             if(colType.equalsIgnoreCase("INT")){
                 rowData.add((Integer)rs.getInt(i));
                 continue;
             }
             if(colType.startsWith("varchar")){
                 rowData.add((String)rs.getString(i));
             continue;
     }
         }
    for (int i = 0; i < tableRows; i++) {
             Row row = new Row(tableDef);
             for (int j = 0; j < rowData.size(); j++) {
             if(colType.equalsIgnoreCase("INT")){
                 row.setInteger(j, (Integer) rowData.get(j));// getting class cast exception here
                     continue;
             }
             if(colType.startsWith("varchar")){

                     row.setCharString(j, (String) rowData.get(j));

           continue;
             }
             }
             //add the row to the table
           table.insert(row);
         }
```

getting exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer  at
>   TableauData.main(TableauData.java:99)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check, if `rowData.get(j)` is Integer, then use `Integer.parseInt(rowData.get(j))` instead of `(Integer) rowData.get(j)`

Comment: if the colType is int then i am setting it using setInteger method, why rowData.get(j) is treated as string

Comment: Because you don't update `colType = rsmds.getColumnTypeName(i);` in second loop. And `colType` always equals to last element in resultset(that likely has String type)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retype String to Integer in a wrong way. You should use `Integer.valueof(rowData.get(j))`

Or you can use

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

As Vadim Beskrovnov suggested. It depends if you want to use Integer as object or primitive data type.